# What is a better way to use 'request' in a ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to use `user=request.user` inside `ModelChoiceField` when I use this method I got an error: `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`.

```
class AlbumForm(forms.Form):
    album = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

The model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class CreateOurColumn(CreateView):
    model = Column
    success_url = reverse_lazy('List-Of-Column')
    form_class = ColumnForm
    template_name = 'create_column.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateOurColumn, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = ColumnFormSet(queryset=Column.objects.none())
        context['album_form'] = AlbumForm()
        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = ColumnFormSet(request.POST)
        album_form = AlbumForm(data=request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid() and album_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset, album_form)

    def form_valid(self, formset, album_form):
        album = album_form.cleaned_data['album']
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.album = album
            instance.save()
        return HtppResponseRedirect('List-Of-Column')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I'm getting the `NameError` is because the request object is not available in the scope of the form definition.

I override the form's `__init__` method and pass the user object as an argument to the form:

```
class AlbumForm(forms.Form):
    album = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Album.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AlbumForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['album'].queryset = Album.objects.filter(user=user)
```

In my `CreateOurColumn` view, inside: `get_context_data` method, I forgot to pass the user object to the `AlbumForm`:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(CreateOurColumn, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['formset'] = ColumnFormSet(queryset=Column.objects.none())
    context['album_form'] = AlbumForm(user=self.request.user)
    return context
```

This way, the `AlbumForm` will filter the `queryset` based on the user object passed to it.

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75898227/19420551)

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly access the request object in the model definition, because the models are parsed at the worker startup, way before someone makes a request. However you can pass the objects in the `constructor`.

```
class AlbumForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user=kwargs.pop('user',None)
        super(AlbumForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['album'].queryset = Album.objects.filter(user=user)

    album = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Album.objects.none())
```

Then in your view you have to create your form like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = AlbumForm(user=request.user)
    ...
    return render(request, 'template.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: But, using: `ModelChoiceField(queryset=Album.objects.none())` wouldn't return `Album` object, because you set it to `objects.none()`, when I visited my form, the object that are in `Album` model is null, why?

Comment: You can use `.all()`, or whatever you want, that part isn't important.

Comment: No, it is important, because when the user is trying to create other model that has foreignkey with an `Album` model, we don't want the user to select the `Album` object that is not their own, that's why we want to use `user=request.user`

Comment: I updated my question now, you can check.